# Qunit testing with no passed Vars

Tags: javascript, testing, qunit

I am trying to make a test of a function that does some pretty simple validation for a form.
However I cannot figure out how to use qunit without passing vars to the function.
here is an example of what I am talking about

```
  function validateForm(){
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var submit = true;
        //do some validation
        //if submit true
        form.submit();
   }
```

all the example of qunit I see in the docs do something like this

```
   ok(validateForm('hello'),'Hello is a valid name');
```

should I just modify my function or is there a way to work with such a setup.

//EDIT

The option I have chosen to pursue right now is setting up another function above the current one that simply parses the form inputs and then sends them as vars to the validateForm() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was modifying the function in a way that allowed me to pass the vars in the test.

before the code would do something like this

```
       function validateForm(){
               var value1 = $('#someinput').val();
               //Do some validation based on these vars
               $('#someform').submit();
        }
```

Now When the submit button is pressed it goes to another function that parses the args out for me also added a 'test' arg so the form is not being submitted during the tests.

```
     function parseFormArgs(){
             var value1 = $('#someinput').val();
             var value2 = $('#otherinput').val();
             var test = false;

             validateForm(value1,value2,test);
     }

     function validateForm(value1,value2,test){
               var submit = true;
               //Do some validation
               if( test != true && submit ){
                   $('#someform').submit();
               }

              return submit;
    }
```

Then my qunit looks something like this

```
      var testFn = true;
      test('validateForm()', function(){
           equals(validateForm('ExampleVal1','ExampleVal2',testFn), false, 'Such and Such Values should not validate');
           ...
           ...
       });
```

Comment: Yep, separate your concerns of getting the values and validating makes it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Does qUnit have access to the form/UI?  I've only used JsTestDriver for JavaScript testing, but there you only test the internal object logic

so instead of trying to read the form (which I don't know if you can do), what you could do is get the current values from the form, and pass those to the validation function, eg:

```
function validate(options){

      return options.foo === "bar"

}
```

so, you could write a qUnit test that did something like

```
var options = {foo:"bar"}
var valid = validate(options)
equal(true, valid)
```

or

```
   var options = {foo:"booboo"}
    var valid = validate(options)
    equal(false, valid)
```

something like that?  Then once you're happy with the function, you can add it into the UI

??

Comment: Right now the Test is separate from the form UI. I want to test multiple scenarios in one file which I think would be tedious to do via the UI inputs

Comment: you should be able to have multiple scenarios in different tests, does my update make sense?